# How to make my SVG fit with background image if it has some white space at the start?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to build a website where I need to overlap two images for the background (one is JPG and the other one is SVG file). But I am unable to overlay both of them as my SVG image has some extra white part in the start page. I want the part from where the gray starts to the bottom. But I am unable to do that.
Here is the SVG code and image : https://www.svgviewer.dev/s/CnqCU38Y

I've tried to do the following with my CSS code, but have failed to get the desired results.

```
.main-page {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
background-image: url('assets/Main-page/bg-cropped.svg'), url('assets/Main-page/1079171177-preview_PosterImage.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}

Here are the images : https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj9Lh.jpg

Can anyone please help me out with this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be `transform="translate(0 0)`:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1920 1134.399" height="1134.399" width="1920" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" y2="0.664" x2="0.969" y1="0.176" id="linear-gradient">
      <stop offset="0"></stop>
      <stop stop-opacity="0" offset="1"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <clipPath id="clip-path">
      <path fill="url(#linear-gradient)" d="M0,0H1920V769.66S1440.573,942.4,960.4,942.4,0,769.66,0,769.66Z" id="bg"></path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(0 0)" data-name="bg" id="bg-2">
    <path fill="url(#linear-gradient)" transform="translate(0 0)" d="M0,0H1920V769.66S1440.573,942.4,960.4,942.4,0,769.66,0,769.66Z" data-name="bg" id="bg-3"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```